# What is the type hint of a function that returns an image?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function that takes 3 `arguments` and returns an image, I want to know that is the **python type hint** that the function returns.

Here is my function:

```py
from PIL import Image

def modify_image(img_path: str, width: int, height: int) -> "what here?":
    """Read and return a resized image"""
    image = Image.open(img_path)
    modified_image = image.resize((width, height))

    return modified_image
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize), both `Image.open()` and `Image.resize` return Pillow `Image` objects, so your function should look something like

```
from PIL import Image

def modify_image(img_path: str, width: int, height: int) -> Image:
    ...
```